# Console Как вставить текст из буфера обмена?

Tags: c#, консоль

Можно ли как нибудь при копирование текста в консоль методом **ctrl + v** вставить копированный текст из буфера в консоль?

P.S: При попытке вставить текст в консоль выпадают знаки:**^v**

Comment: А какая у вас операционка? У меня на Windows 10 Ctrl+V работает в консоли.

Comment: Попробуйте `Ctrl+Shift+V`

Comment: Если нет, попробуйте правый клик, там в меню наверняка есть вставка.

Comment: @VladD, ОС: 7-x64! Но проблема в том что через c# в консоли нету пкм вариантов вставки или копирование :( , только клавишами! Попробовал способ **Evgeniy**, не получилось.

Comment: @ArteS: Попробуйте тогда системное меню (левый клик по иконке в title bar'е слева или Alt-Пробел) и там пункт «Изменить».

Comment: @VladD, 0о точняк) Ну я просто думал что можно как-то проще использовать при вставки никуда не нажимая) Ну это походу уже надо хук ставить на перехват ctrl + v )

Comment: @ArteS: Или перелезть на десятку :)

Comment: `Shift` + `Insert`

Comment: @Umed, это не помогло! Зато я сделал следующее, во свойствах консоли поставил в поле `Правка` > `Выделение мышью` и теперь текст сам вставляется при клике пкм мыши)

Comment: @ArteS, хорошо, когда проблемы находят решения :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Windows 7 (и кажется в младших версиях тоже) работает открытие системного меню (левый клик по иконке в title bar'е слева или <kbd>Alt + Пробел</kbd>) и в нём пункт «Изменить». Если включить режим «быстрой вставки» (см. скриншот ниже), должно работать системное меню по правой кнопке мыши.

В Windows 10 по умолчанию работает <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd>, а также правая кнопка мыши открывает контекстное меню, в котором есть пункт «Вставить». Если вдруг это не работает, нужно открыть системное меню (левый клик по иконке в title bar'е слева), выбрать «настройки», и включить разрешение там:

[image: Ctrl-C Ctrl-V]

---

Причина этого — то, что шорткат <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> для консольных приложений традиционно означал не «копировать», а «завершить программу». Разработчики опасались, что если разрешить <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> для вставки, пользователи пользоваться <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> с целью копирования, и будут останавливать тем самым консольные приложения. К версии Windows 10 разработчики консоли таки сдались требованиям пользователей.